# Can I use transit visa for visa run from India to Sri Lanka on normal return ticket?

Tags: air-travel, india, transit-visas, visa-runs, sri-lanka

We are a family of five Lithuanians (EU citizens). Currently, we are in India on one year multiple entry tourist visas and need to do a visa run every 90 days. I have checked and Sri Lanka gives [free transit visas for 2 days](https://www.eta.gov.lk/slvisa/visainfo/fees.jsp), which for me would be excellent to do a visa run.

If I would buy simple return tickets with one day layover would it work in this case? If not can destination be a different port in India or it has to be a different country?

Comment: I’d be careful if I were you - one visa run might be ok but a second could end in denial of entry when you try to return to India. Tourist visas are generally not intended to be used to effectively live in the country you’re visiting.

Comment: @Traveller Hi, our visas is not double but multiple entry, so one would assume that more than two entries should be fine. We'll see shortly...

Comment: @MatasVaitkevicius any update on how it went?

Comment: @MarkMayoSupportsMonica Hi, didn't go to Sri Lanka sounded too risky.